# SSIS export data to excel empty

Tags: excel, ssis

I have weird problem: I have data in DB, when I click on Preview... in Ole DB Sources I see data but when I link them to Excel - the document is empty only firs row with name is there. When I debug project I have red cross in excel file and information:

Data viewer at path 'OLE DB Source Output' of task 'Data Flow Task' [DataflowID: {6007EF3C-0A2C-45C9-995D-FA9DF2F5CE9C}; IDString: Paths[OLE DB Source.OLE DB Source Output]; PackageRPath: test2\Package.dtsx]

What is going on???

Comment: I dont have excel in this computer but with Flat File is thesame

Comment: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this run-time error is excel do not have 64-bit driver which is selected by default in SSIS running on 64bit OS. So solution is also hidden behind the reason, change the driver from default and you are good to go.

Navigate to Project-> [PROJECT_NAME] Properties.
Navigate to “Debugging” option from left panel and from Right panel change Run64BitRuntime value to false.